# Input fields in console in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, console

I'm looking for a convenient way to input certain data, for example, date.

I want to create an input prompt in a console program that would look like this:

Enter date: ----/--/--

Where dashes are input "fields". So if I press "2","0","1","5","0","1","1","5", it would look like

Enter date: 2015/01/15

And if I press more keys - it would do nothing. So it's an input prompt that has a limited amount of input-able characters. And of course, if I press Backspace - it would erase characters and put dashes back.

I think I know how to make it in Python, but I am wondering if this input prompt system has already been created. Is there a module (or maybe an easy trick) that would let me create such an input prompt?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use the built in `input()` function. Here is a sample:

```
myDate=str(input("Enter date ---/--/--:"))
myDate=myDate.split("/") #assuming they input with slashes
Year=int(myDate[0])
Month=int(myDate[1])
Day=int(myDate[2])
```

Comment: mmmmm, it's not what I'm really looking for. I need the inputted text to appear in the place of dashes.

Comment: Well, I don't know of an "easy trick", especially if you don't know the console height beforehand.